# Running a controller code for all the pages using Content Inheritance

Tags: crafter-cms

We want to run a common controller(groovy) code on all the pages. Can I set up Content Inheritance by using a controller using level-descriptor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can. Create a node selector with variable name `scripts` in the level descriptor content type (aka Section Defaults). Then in the Section Defaults, from the node selector, select the script you want to execute on every page.